# Function in VBScript returns a syntax error, when I know the function works in another script version

Tags: function, syntax, vbscript

I had a script that queries a single computer's WMI for every user that has logged into a computer and returns the Month, Day, Year, Hour, Min, Sec that the user last logged in.  The original script works just fine, using the function that is causing the syntax error in the new version.

I added code to have the same script query against list of computers by reading a servers.txt file.  The code kept failing with a generic syntax error at the line that starts the function I used to convert the sTime into human readable form.  I took out the function and the script runs just fine, but then the Last Logon time is in the format "20150323132329.000000-420".

Not being a VBScript expert I don't understand what is wrong with syntax when it works fine in one version of the script but the exact same function in a different version of the script fails with a syntax error.

I'm hoping someone would be kind enough to help me figure out what I am doing wrong, understanding that I'm not a strong scripting person to begin with.

Again, if I take out the function completely and alter the line `objFile.WriteLine " Last Logon: " & ConvertTime(objItem.LastLogon)`
to `objFile.WriteLine " Last Logon: " & objItem.LastLogon`
The script runs exactly as I expect but then I lose the formatting of the last logon time.

This is the script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("output.txt", True)
Set objServerlist = objFSO.OpenTextFile("servers.txt", 1)

On Error Resume Next
Do Until objServerList.AtEndOfStream
    strComputer = objServerList.ReadLine
Set objWMIService = GetObject _
    ("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate,authenticationLevel=pktPrivacy}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkLoginProfile",,48)

function ConvertTime(sTime)
if (sTime="**************.******+***") then
  ConvertTime = "Unknown"
else
  if (Trim(sTime)="") then
   sTime="Unknown"
  else
   sYear = Mid(sTime,1,4)
   sMonth = Mid(sTime,5,2)
   sDay = Mid(sTime,7,2)
   sHour = Mid(sTime,9,2)
   sMin = Mid(sTime,11,2)
   sSec = Mid(sTime,13,2)
  end if 
  ConvertTime = sMonth & "/" & sDay & "/" & sYear & " (" & sHour & ":" & sMin & ":" & sSec & ")"
end if
end function

For Each objItem in colItems
if (objItem.UserType = "Normal Account") then
    objFile.WriteLine objItem.Name & vbCrLf
    objFile.WriteLine " Last Logon: " & ConvertTime(objItem.LastLogon)
    objFile.WriteLine " Number of Logons: " & objItem.NumberOfLogons 
     if (objItem.Privileges=0) then
      objFile.WriteLine " (Guest Account)"
     else if (objItem.Privileges=1) then
      objFile.WriteLine " (Standard User Account)"
      else if (objItem.Privileges=2) then
       objFile.WriteLine " (Administrator Account)"
      end if
     end if
    end if
    objFile.WriteLine vbCrLf
end if   
Next
Loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty surprised this ever worked.

While you can have a function declaration in between module-level lines of code, you cannot have it inside a control flow block, such as `Do...Loop`.

Move the function declaration to be at the module level, outside of any `If`s, `Do`s and other functions.

On a side note, the function probably does not do what you think it does (did you mean `ConvertTime="Unknown"` instead of `sTime="Unknown"`?).

Comment: This is where I am confused, how could I move that function outside of the Do...Loop and still have it parse for every server in the servers.txt?

Comment: Because this is how functions work in general - you declare them in one place and use in another. You are calling the function from a `For` loop that is inside a `Do` loop. If you needed to put functions inside loops, you'd be concerned why it works why being declared outside of the `For` loop.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Move the function block outside of the `Do` block. Make it the very first or the very last thing in the file for readability. Keep the rest in the `Do` block.